# UberSVN switch to 1.7

Tags: svn, ubersvn

I have just updated all my svn clients in my work to use 1.7 which is compatible with UberSVN, which has the ability to switch to 1.7.

I have just done the switch and updated everything, but all I am getting now is:

```
 uberSVN Binaries Switch in progress
 uberSVN needs to restart to complete the installation, give us about a minute before you log back
 in.
```

Does anybody know how long it takes to actually complete the switch over, I mean this has been going on for about 1.5 hours now and It's still not complete. Any ideas or do you think it's just not doing anything and has 'crashed'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't take that long.

If you close the window and then try to go back to the uberSVN portal, log in and go back to the SVN Switch tab - Has it switched over?

Can you see if Apache is still running? What OS are you on?

I'd also be interested to see what's in the ubersvn/data/logs/PackageTool_out.log file - Do you see any errors?

Also, try restarting the uberSVN portal.

Comment: Well I only just got your answer now, so I just checked it after leaving it all weekend and it is still saying the same thing. I have just logged in again and it takes me straight to that screen. I am running Arch Linux and here is the output of that file: 

[richc@DevServer logs]$ cat PackageTool_out.log
Attempting to switch the running Subversion to version 1.7
Currently running on version 1.6
Available versions are:
   1.7
   1.6
Stopping Apache...
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

Comment: Stopping Tomcat...
Tomcat did not stop in time. PID file was not removed.
Services stopped
Unable to switch Subversion version to 1.7: /home/ubersvn/bin/svnserve (Text file busy)
Starting Apache...
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
Starting Tomcat...
Existing PID file found during start.
Tomcat appears to still be running with PID 2906. Start aborted.
Services started